# Wpf ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have been binding wpf `ListBox` in `Dispatcher` using following code

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                   LoadData();                      
                }));

 private void LoadData()
 {
    // Written some logic here 
 }
```

It bind the `ListBox` well but When i call

```
ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(routeList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
```

It always returns me `null`.Problem only occur when i bind the `ListBox` inside  `Dispatcher`. If i bind the same `ListBox` in Class Constructor, it works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Items containers are generated in a separate dispatcher operation. As a result, you've got null.

We should always think about container generation as an operation which executes asynchronously.

It is possible to listen `StatusChanged` event of the `ItemContainer` which gives information about whether `ItemConteiner` is created.

So to be sure `ItemContainer` is generated, you should attach to the `StatusChanged` event and check for the `ContainersGenerated` status.

For example:

```
yourListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += new EventHandler(ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged);  

private void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    if (this.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)  
    {  
        // Do something here...  
    }  
}
```

You can find [more information here](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/item-containers/).